# How to prove this inequality involving a small number?

Tags: inequality

Let $\varepsilon$ be a small enough positive number, we want to show:
$\frac{(0.5-\varepsilon)^2}{(0.5-\varepsilon)^2+(0.5+\varepsilon)^2}\geq 0.5-(4-\varepsilon)\varepsilon$. I tested it numerically and did not find any contradiction.

My trial is as follows: $0.5-(4-\varepsilon)\varepsilon=\frac{0.5-(4-\varepsilon)\varepsilon}{0.5-(4-\varepsilon)\varepsilon+0.5+(4-\varepsilon)\varepsilon}$, and try to prove
$(0.5-\varepsilon)^2\geq 0.5-(4-\varepsilon)\varepsilon$ and $(0.5+\varepsilon)^2 \leq 0.5+(4-\varepsilon)\varepsilon$. But the first auxiliary inequality does not hold.

Comment: You can use algebra to get a quartic equation, and then a combination of the rational roots theorem, factoring, and possibly even the quadratic formula, you can solve for all epsilon which make it zero. You can then use calculus to find intervals of epsilon which hold the general inequality. Or, you can just graph it and do it visually, if you don't need to be too rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$
f(\varepsilon)=  \frac{(0.5-\varepsilon)^2}{(0.5-\varepsilon)^2+(0.5+\varepsilon)^2}- 0.5+(4-\varepsilon)\varepsilon
$$
we have
$$
f(0)=0
$$
After some tedious calculation you have that the derivative is
$$
f'(\varepsilon)=\dfrac{-2\varepsilon^5+4\varepsilon^4-\varepsilon^3+\frac{5}{2}\varepsilon^2-\frac{1}{8}\epsilon+\frac{1}{8}}{\left(\varepsilon^2+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}
$$
so
$$
f'(0)>0
$$
As the function is $0$ for $\varepsilon=0$ and is increasing in $0$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(\varepsilon)>0$